# ReactJS - How does one delete a button component, that was just clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling

My aim is to delete the button, I have just clicked. I understand there may be numerous ways such as creating a deleteButton component, and setting the state appropriately.

However, my return function in the main App component will also render another button (this I can do), but I think this may add to the complexity.

I'm currently struggling to pin-point the ideal solution, so please help.

Comment: you can add a uniqueid to each delete button and delete it

Comment: first give the unique id for particular button and use **splice** method and if you display the button using mapping method then give index as id for that button and add splice method in function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've managed to solve my question, although I'm sure there's other ways too.

To further clarify...

I had a form which I wished to render, when clicking on a 'Create' Button.

At the same time, I wished to remove the 'Create' button, once clicked.

The end result is to only display the form and nest a new button in the return function.

1) Set the initial state of the form to false:

```
this.state = {
  displayForm: false,
}
```

2) Then use setState within the displayForm function to allow for the change in state, once the button is clicked:

```
displayForm(){
  this.setState({
    displayForm: !this.state.displayForm {/* true */}
  })
}
```

3) set a style object within the render function, such as:

```
render() {
  const btnStyle = {
    display: 'block',
  } ...
```

4) Use an IF statement to change the display style of the button if the form has been rendered

```
if(this.state.displayForm){
  btnStyle.display = 'none'
}
```

5) Now, within the return function, use your JSX tags appropriately and call the function onClick, as well as the style to be applied.

```
<Button
  style={btnStyle}
  onClick={() => {
    this.displayForm()
  }}>Create</button>
  {this.state.displayForm && ([
   <Form />,
   <br />,
   <Button>Add Schema</Button>,
  ])}
```

NOTE: the < Form /> and < Button /> components have been imported and added here.

So, once the 'Create' button has been clicked, the form displays (true), and thereby the 'Create' button disappears from the Virtual DOM. I've also nested another (new) button as intended, underneath the form.